# How do you run middleware functions post response in Phoenix framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I'm developing a simple website in Elixir with Phoenix. I'd like to add some custom middleware that runs *after* a response has been generated. For example, in order to log the total number of bytes in each response I'd like to have a Plug like this

```
defmodule HelloWeb.Plugs.ByteLogger do
  import Plug.Conn
  require Logger

  def init(default), do: default

  def call(conn, default) do
    log("bytes sent: #{String.length(conn.resp_body)}")
  end
end
```

Trying to use this plug in one of the Phoenix pipelines in the router won't work though, they are all run before the response is rendered. Instead it causes a `FunctionClauseError` since `conn.resp_body` is `nil`. I'm not sure how to use this plug so it can run after the response is rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [register_before_send/2](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#register_before_send/2).

This allows to register callbacks that will be called before `resp_body` gets set to nil as [explained here](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#module-response-fields).

Should look like:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.Plugs.ByteLogger do
  import Plug.Conn
  require Logger

  def init(default), do: default

  def call(conn, default) do
    register_before_send(conn, fn conn ->
      log("bytes sent: #{String.length(conn.resp_body)}")

      conn
    end)
  end
end
```

Edit: I don't think you should be using `String.length` for the byte size:

- `resp_body` is not necessarily a string, can be an I/O-list
- `byte_size/1` should be used to count bytes, `String.length/1` returns UTF-8 grapheme count

The following could do the job, but with a significant performance impact due to the need of concatenating the body:

```
conn.resp_body |> to_string() |> byte_size()
```

[:erlang.iolist_size/1](https://erldocs.com/current/erts/erlang.html?i=0&search=iolist#iolist_size/1) seems to work well and I suppose is much better performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks! I switched to `IO.iodata_length(conn.resp_body)` for the response size and it seems to be working

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `IO.iodata_length/1`.
Apparently it is literally the same under the hood (`&IO.iodata_length/1
` evaluates to `&:erlang.iolist_size/1` because it is inlined), but feels nicer to use. TIL, thanks!